# Creating a list with model results using multiple loops in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I am running a few iterations of a regression model. In each iteration I change the values of two parameters, `i` and `k`, then I store each outcome in a list with `j` elements.  For this specific case, `i` can take 3 values, `k` can take 2 values, while `j` equals the total of combinations of `i` and `k`, in this case 6.

However, for some reason, every element `j` of the list of outcomes stores the same result. I guess I am doing something wrong in the way I am writing the loop but I cannot find where the error is. My code is as follows:

```
library("plm")
set.seed(123)

##random dataset
n <- 100  
y <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)  
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 5, sd = 2)  
x2 <- rnorm(n, mean = -2, sd = 3)  
x3 <- rnorm(n, mean = 1, sd = 0.5)  
df <- data.frame(y, x1 ,x2 ,x3)

id_values <- 1:4  
time_values <- 1999:2002  
combinations <- expand.grid(ID = id_values, TIME = time_values)
panel_data <- merge(combinations, df, by = c("ID", "TIME"), all.x = TRUE)
panel_data[is.na(panel_data)] <- 0 


##regression model

model <- vector('list', length = 6) ## is length even needed here?

for (j in c(1:6)) {
  for (i in c(1,3,5)) {
    for (k in c("time", "twoways")) {
  model[[j]] <- plm(log(y) ~ lag(log(x),i) + lag(log(x2),i) + lag(log(x3),i),
                   model = "within", effect = k,
                   data = panel_data) 
  print("                  +++***+++***+++***+++***+++***+++***+++            ")
  print(c("number of lags", i))
  print(summary(model[[j]], vcov.=vcovSSC(model[[j]])))
    }
  }
}
```

Now, a solution could be to use an external index as follows

```
index <- 1
for (i in c(1, 3, 5)) {
  for (k in c("time", "twoways")) {
    model[[index]] <- plm(log(y) ~ lag(log(x), i) + lag(log(x2), i) + lag(log(x3), i),
                         model = "within", effect = k,
                         data = panel_data) 
    print("                  +++***+++***+++***+++***+++***+++***+++            ")
    print(c("number of lags", i))
    print(summary(model[[index]], vcov. = vcovSSC(model[[index]])))
    index <- index + 1
  }
}
```

However, for the sake of curiosity I would like to understand what the issue is with the third loop I wrote and how may Io fix the code so to keep the three different loops.

Comment: Your example produces an error on the line `panel_data <- merge(combinations, df, by = c("ID", "TIME"), all.x = TRUE)` because df doesn't contain columns with those names. Buy since you are running the outer loop, you are running both inner loops 6 times. And since you overwrite `model[[j]]` each time, its will always just be the value from the last of the two inner loops. You are just doing six times more duplicate work with the additional third outer loop. You already have included the correct version below. You can't translate that to a for loop.

Comment: A `for` loop is more than an index - it repeats the code inside. You have 3 `i` values and 2 `k` values, so you want `2 * 3 = 6` models fit. Your second code does this. Your first code  wraps it in `for(j in 1:6) {...}` - every time through your `j` loop it fits 6 models, and you go through that loop 6 times so you end up fitting `6 * 2 * 3 = 36` models, each of the 6 models get fit 6 times. But since you don't use `i` or `k` (or an external index) in assigning the results, you fit 36 models but only save `6` of them, which happen to be the last one fit for each `j` value.

Comment: Thanks to both. It makes sense, I was just multiplying iterations by 6 and just overwriting the last j spot.

Comment: Also a better solution would be to replace the index with `index <- paste("lag_", i, "eff_", k, sep = "_")`  to keep track of the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens in an even simplier loop

```
model <- vector('list', length = 6)
for (j in c(1:6)) {
  for (i in c(1,3,5)) {
    for (k in c("time", "twoways")) {
      model[[j]] <- list(i, k)
      cat(paste0("model[[", j, "]]<-", capture.output(dput(model[[j]]))), "\n")
    }
  }
  cat("...\n")
}
```

the output is

```
model[[1]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[1]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[1]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[1]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[1]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[1]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
model[[2]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[2]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[2]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[2]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[2]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[2]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
model[[3]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[3]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[3]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[3]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[3]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[3]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
model[[4]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[4]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[4]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[4]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[4]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[4]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
model[[5]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[5]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[5]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[5]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[5]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[5]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
model[[6]]<-list(1, "time") 
model[[6]]<-list(1, "twoways") 
model[[6]]<-list(3, "time") 
model[[6]]<-list(3, "twoways") 
model[[6]]<-list(5, "time") 
model[[6]]<-list(5, "twoways") 
...
```

So you aren't running the code 6 times, you're running it 36 times. And the value you are storing at each index is just the value for 5 and "twoways" because you keep overwriting the value at `model[[j]]` each time in the groups separated by "..."

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank you